# Numerical methods for one-dimensional Bayesian inference

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, numerical-integration

I am doing inference using a Bayesian model that has only one variable, which boils down to computing a (one-dimensional) cumulative distribution and a quantile function given the log of a probability density function.

This is much simpler than the usual multivariate setting, so I would like to have a very fast (order of milliseconds) and robust implementation.

I was wondering, if maybe this case has an elegant solution detailed somewhere in the literature? All I manage to find myself is discussion of MCMC and other "heavy" methods.